# SoundCloud SC.Widget.Events.FINISH Not Firing Anymore HTML5 Widget

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I just noticed recently that the SC.Widget.Events.FINISH event is no longer firing in the HTML5 widget API for a playlist. The following code was working fine before, but now no longer performs the function when the song finishes:

http://jsbin.com/vujedofada/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    widget = SC.Widget(iframe);        
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log("Ready");
        widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function() {
            //Get info for song playing
            widget.getCurrentSound(function(currentSound) {
                console.log(currentSound.id + " " + currentSound.title + " " + currentSound.artwork_url);
                sid = currentSound.id
                stitle = currentSound.title
                sartlo = currentSound.artwork_url
                display_artwork()
            });
        });         
        widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {        
            console.log("Finish");
            play_next_shuffled_song();
        });
        widget.getSounds(function(sounds) {
            create_shuffled_indexes(sounds.length);
            play_next_shuffled_song();
        });               
    });
});
```

The READY and PLAY events appear to be working and FINISH works for the widget with a single track, just not a playlist.

Can someone from SoundCloud please confirm if this is a known bug and when it will be corrected?

Comment: working on it https://soundcloudcommunity.com/share-embed-230064/html5-widget-sc-widget-events-finish-event-doesn-t-fire-when-song-in-playlist-finishes-7391734/index1.html#post18022392

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. This should be fixed now.

https://soundcloudcommunity.com/share-embed-230064/html5-widget-sc-widget-events-finish-event-doesn-t-fire-when-song-in-playlist-finishes-7391734/index1.html#post18023517

Comment: Awesome, it's working properly again. Thanks Tom and team!